# AWS Cloudfront alternate domain name 403 forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have set up a cloudfront distribution successfully and I am able to navigate to the default domain provided by Cloudfront. I have also set up a alternate domain name using AWS Certificate Manager (ACM). The SSL has been issued and verified by the cname record I added.

For the cname entry in Google Domains I am using:

www CNAME cloudfront-distribution-name.cloudfront.net

When I try to navigate to the alternate domain: domain.com I receive a 403 forbidden network response. See screenshot below:

Note: I set up the cloudfront distribution using a website endpoint as the origin.

[image]

Here is the origin config:

[image]

Here is the behavior config:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the origin config?

Comment: Origin config has been added.

Comment: Is it starting with `http` or `https`?

Comment: Neither. The docs I read said to remove the http/https in the Origin Domain Name.

Comment: Ok, make sense. Could you also post the behaviour?

Comment: Behavior config has been added. Also, I was unable to add the Certificate as www.domain.com. It would not validate with my DNS. I instead used domain.com for the Certificate and it was validated and issued. This is the Cert I am using and I have domain.com as the alternate domain name.

Comment: Try invalidating the cache.

Comment: Tried that. Did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the issue. Go to cloudfront and then under the 'general' tab select edit. Add a Cert with two domain names:

`domain.com`
`*.domain.com`

Add the appropriate CNAME record to verify the SSL cert. Then add another CNAME record to verify the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com). It should look something like this in your DNS:

Record Name: `_2958323dad0598j4cb4e722d0d8k5921.domain.com`
Type: CNAME
Value: `_7sk82036f90ffb2be52p922c080174f8.bsgbmzkfwj.acm-validations.aws`

Note: For certain DNS providers you will not include the `.domain.com` portion as this gets automatically added. (Google domains is one example)

Record Name: `www.domain.com`
Type: CNAME
Value: `x8k4nz5ok8a8dj.cloudfront.net`

Note: For certain DNS providers you will not include the `.domain.com` portion it will just be `www` for the CNAME record.

Comment: You saved my night :D I spent 5h to get this done, because of your suggestion to add *.domain.com I was able to get some sleep :D thanks a lot!

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but this solution didn't help me. 
Is there any change?